# NodeJS OOP counter that can trigger at different intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to make a small NodeJS app that checks an external website every X minutes.

To begin with I just want to check one website, but when that works, then check multiple.

Since I later want to be able to check multiple websites, I suppose it would make sense to create a class, so `example1.com` can be checked every `n` minutes, and website `B` every `j` minutes, so each website object can have their own counter?

## My attempt

```
const fetchWebsite = delay => {
  console.log('Fetch website after ' + delay + ' seconds');
}

setInterval(() => {
  setTimeout(fetchWebsite, 1000, 1);
  setTimeout(fetchWebsite, 2000, 2);
}, 1000)
```

which gives

```
Fetch website after 1 seconds
Fetch website after 2 seconds
Fetch website after 1 seconds
Fetch website after 2 seconds
...
```

where this is printed every 1 second, where I would have expected

```
Fetch website after 1 seconds
Fetch website after 1 seconds
Fetch website after 2 seconds
Fetch website after 1 seconds
Fetch website after 1 seconds
Fetch website after 2 seconds
...
```

## Question

Can anyone figure out why the second `fetchWebsite` is printed every time and not only every 2 second?

Any help on how to OOP my attemp would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your interval runs every second, so website 2 is fetched every second, too. You need two separate intervals, not two separate timeouts.

Comment: Looks like a basic misunderstanding of what is `setInterval` vs `setTimer`.

Comment: "*I suppose it would make sense to create a class*" - no. Unless you want to create an instance that you can interact with later in different ways, you don't need a `class` - a simple function will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set new timeouts in interval of 1 sec. This is wrong in your case.
Check this code (upd. with timer functionality):

```
// Fetching function
const fetchWebsite = (delay, param) => console.log(`Fetch website ${param} after ${delay} seconds`);

// Interval creator
const runInterval = (fn, delay, param) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    // Init and run monitor
    if(!monitor[param]) monitor[param] = 1000;
    monitor[param] += delay;
    // Run function
    fn(delay, param);
  }, delay)
}

// Simple running monitor
const monitor = {};

// Run interval 1
runInterval(fetchWebsite, 1000, 1);

// Run interval 2 after 3 sec
setTimeout(() => {
  runInterval(fetchWebsite, 2000, 2);
}, 3000);

// Check monitor after 10 sec
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(monitor)
}, 10000);
```

Example [is here](https://jsbin.com/fesamoy/7/edit?js,console)

Comment: Incredible. It is possible to have each `fetchWebsite` know for how many seconds they have been running for? For instead of eg `after 2000 mili seconds` it would say `22 seconds` when it have been running for 22 seconds?

Comment: Of course it's possible) You need to add monitor object, put your links there as 'key' => 'value' and update them within interval. I will update my answer with timer functionality.